# How to display agenda start day / end day in the header-line?

Tags: org-agenda, header-line

I'm trying to display the `org-starting-day` in the header line using the code below. It's working when I first display the agenda but it is not updated when I navigate forward / backward in the agenda. I guess I need some eval but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
  #'(lambda ()
      (setq header-line-format
            (format-time-string "%e %B %Y" org-starting-day))))
```

Here is the result with a slightly modified code:

[image]

Comment: `org-starting-day` is a scratch variable that is used by the agenda code. You should not be consulting it at all. What exactly do you want to display in the mode line?

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing the output of the code in the header line.

Comment: I'm confused: do you want to modify the header line in the agenda or the mode line of the agenda buffer? You say "here's the result wiht a slighly modified code": can you show the code? Is the result  you show  the result you want? If yes, then what is the question? If not, what result do you want?

Comment: `mode-line` or `header-line` is not important. The result is what I want to achieve BUT it works only when the agenda is first shown. If I navigate the agenda ('f' or 'b' key fore example), the displayed date is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a slightly more complex code:

```
(defun iso-time (sd)
  (pcase-let ((`(,m ,d ,y) (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute sd)))
    (encode-time 0 0 0 d m y)))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook  #'(lambda ()
 (if org-agenda-overriding-arguments
     (setq agenda-start (iso-time (nth 1 org-agenda-overriding-arguments))
           agenda-span            (nth 2 org-agenda-overriding-arguments))
   (setq agenda-start org-starting-day
         agenda-span  org-agenda-span))
 (cond
  ((and (numberp agenda-span) (> agenda-span 1))
   (setq agenda-end (time-add agenda-start (* agenda-span 24 3600)))
   (setq agenda-range (concat (format-time-string "%e %B %Y" agenda-start)
                              " - "
                              (format-time-string "%e %B %Y" agenda-end))))
  ;; Weekly view
  ((eq agenda-span 'week)
   (setq agenda-end (time-add agenda-start (* 7 24 3600)))
   (setq agenda-range (concat (format-time-string "%e %B %Y" agenda-start)
                              " - "
                              (format-time-string "%e %B %Y" agenda-end))))
  ;; Two weeks view
  ((eq agenda-span 'fortnight)
   (setq agenda-end (time-add agenda-start (* 14 24 3600)))
   (setq agenda-range (concat (format-time-string "%e %B %Y" agenda-start)
                              " - "
                              (format-time-string "%e %B %Y" agenda-end))))
  ;; Month view
  ((eq agenda-span 'month)
   (setq agenda-range (concat (format-time-string "%B %Y " agenda-start))))
  ;; Default
  (t
   (setq agenda-range (concat (format-time-string "%e %B %Y " agenda-start)))))
 (setq header-line-format agenda-range)))
```

Comment: `encode-time` has changed signature recently (emacs 27 perhaps?) and while it still recognizes the old convention, there may come a time when that goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation that uses `org-agenda-finalize-hook`. The hook is run when the agenda is first run and also when the agenda is changed and `org-agenda-redo` is called, e.g. when you change the view from, say, a weekly agenda to a monthly agenda: the starting and ending dates are recalculated and redisplayed.

The implementation depends on the following details:
when the agenda is displayed, text properties are added to every line. You can check those properties with `C-u C-x =` with the cursor at the beginning of each line. The lines that contain the dates are distinguished by having the `org-date-line` property set to `t`. In addition, the date lines have a `day` property whose value is the absolute (i.e. Julian calendar) day number of that date, e.g. for today (2020-07-16) the value of the `day` property is 737622. You can turn an absolute day number into a calendar-like `(month day year)` date, using the following function:

```el
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp :results drawer
    (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute 737622)
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS:
  :results:
  (7 16 2020)
  :end:
```

The function `ndk/org-agenda-first-last-day` below calculates the first day of the displayed agenda by going to the beginning of the agenda buffer and moving forward until it finds the first line with the `org-date-line` property, and then gets the value of the `day` property: that's the first day of the agenda. Similarly, it calculates the last day by going to the end of the buffer and moving backwards until it finds a date line: that's the last day of the agenda. It then returns a list of the two days:

```el
(defun ndk/org-agenda-first-last-day ()
   "Assumption: we are in the agenda buffer.
    Returns the first and last day of the current agenda
    as integers (Julian dates)."
   (let (first last)
     (save-excursion
       ;; find the first date line
       (goto-char (point-min))
       (setq first
         (catch 'first
           (while (equal (forward-line) 0)
             (when (get-text-property (point) 'org-date-line)
               (throw 'first (get-text-property (point-at-bol) 'day))))))
       ;; find the last date line
       (goto-char (point-max))
       (setq last
         (catch 'last
           (while (equal (forward-line -1) 0)
             (when (get-text-property (point) 'org-date-line)
               (throw 'last (get-text-property (point-at-bol) 'day)))))))
     (list (or first (org-today)) (or last (org-today)))))
```

Note that there is no checking that we are in the agenda buffer, but since this will be called from the `org-agenda-finalize-hook`, there is not much danger: but even if you go calling it in an arbitrary buffer, it will return two "today"s, although it might take a long time to do so... The same thing happens in other agenda views (e.g. the global TODO list) where no such text properties are found. Since this function will still be called in such cases, we need to make sure that whatever it returns does not raise errors: today's absolute day will satisfy the calendar call below and seems like a reasonable default.

The next function calls `ndk/org-agenda-first-last-day` above, converts the absolute day numbers to gregorian `(month day year)` lists, using the calendar function `calendar-gregorian-from-absolute`, and then formats a string with the two dates and sets the header line:

```el
(defun ndk/org-agenda-first-last-day-head ()
   (let ((dates (mapcar #'calendar-gregorian-from-absolute 
                        (org-agenda-first-last-day))))
    (setq header-line-format
       (format "%s TO %s"
               (format-time-string (org-agenda-format-date-aligned (nth 0 dates)))
               (format-time-string (org-agenda-format-date-aligned (nth 1 dates)))))))
```

The formatting leaves a lot to be desired, but that should be easy to adjust to taste.

Finally, we add this last function to `org-agenda-finalize-hook`, so that it gets called at `org-agenda-finalize` time. As noted above, this happens both when the agenda is created to begin with and after every reformatting that calls `org-agenda-redo`:

```el
(eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  '(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'ndk/org-agenda-first-last-day-head))
```

And that's all: all the code needs to be added to the init file: the `add-hook` has to be done after `org-agenda` is loaded to make sure that `org-agenda-finalize-hook` is defined, hence the `eval-after-load`. Since the agenda uses `calendar`, when the agenda is loaded, `calendar` will be loaded as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I learned a lot. However, the solution I posted is simpler and probably more robust.

Comment: You are depending on an udocumented, scratch variable as I pointed out in a comment: that's hardly robust.